# How to update Python 2.7 to 3 in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, terminal

I'm trying to run a python3 script through terminal on my mac, but every time I execute the file terminal uses Python 2.7 despite 3.7 being installed.

I have read in other threads that python3 can be run by using the "python3" command, but this seems to load me into the python syntax with ">>>" at the beginning of every line

Is there a way of running python 3 while using whatever syntax is native to terminal?

Or as a last resort what is the command to run a .py file from the python syntax?

Comment: `python3 a.py` has to work

Comment: I think you are just typing python3 without the file name so just chage your command to python3 myprogram.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run a python script from the terminal in python3 use:

```
python3 python-file.py
```

if you want to write it this way `python python-file.py` you have to create a symbolic link from `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3` by using the command (**only do this if you know what you are doing**):

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

if you want to run the file using `./python-file.py` you have to add a ["shebang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: I do strongly recommend against changing /usr/bin/python from version 2 to 3 unless you know very well what you are doing. It can break many scripts.

Comment: A better shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking! Thankyou

Comment: As a side note, arch and fedora already have /usr/bin/python as python3 (Arch since ages, fedora pretty recently)

Answer (score 4):

1. Install ppa

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

2. Update packages

`sudo apt-get update`

3. Upgrade python 2.x to python 3.x

`sudo apt-get install python3.6`

**Change default python**

`sudo rm /usr/bin/python`

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

**Check default version**

`python -V`